# SQL query format

Tags: python, sql, database, tuples, database-performance

I have a list of string that I need to pass to an sql query.

```
        listofinput = []
        for i in input:
         listofinput.append(i)
        if(len(listofinput)>1):
         listofinput = format(tuple(listofinput))
```

```
sql_query = f"""SELECT *  FROM countries
                                where
                                name in {listofinput};
                                """
```

This works when I have a list, but in case of just one value it fails.

```
as listofinput = ['USA'] for one value 
but listofinput ('USA', 'Germany') for multiple
```

also I need to do this for thousands of input, what is the best optimized way to achieve the same. name in my table countries is an indexed column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just convert to tuple and then if the second last character is a coma, remove it.

```py
listofinput = format(tuple(input))

if listofinput[-2] == ",":
    listofinput = f"{listofinput[:-2]})"

sql_query = f"""SELECT *  FROM countries
where name in {listofinput};"""
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `if(len(listofinput)>1):` to `if(len(listofinput)>=1):`
This might work.

Comment: Nope he will get an extra comma that will be syntax error in sql

Answer (score 0):

Remove condition `if(len(listofinput)>1)` .

Because if you don't convert to tuple your query should be like this:

```sql
... where name in ['USA']
```

or

```sql
... where name in []
```

and `in [...]` not acceptable in `SQL`, only `in (...)` is acceptable.

You can remove `format()` too:

```py
listofinput = tuple(listofinput)
```

**Final Code:**

```py
listofinput = []
for i in input:
  listofinput.append(i)
listofinput = tuple(listofinput)

sql_query = f"""SELECT *  FROM countries
                WHERE
                name IN {listofinput};
                """
```

Comment: I ```input``` if 2nd line means input from console, you should it change to something else, too. like ```input().split()``` that needs that enter `space seperated` string in console. like ```USA GERMANY```.

Answer (score 0):

Yes the tuple with one element will required a ","
To circumvent your problem, maybe you can use string instead by just changing your code to the below:

```
listofinput = []
for i in input:
   listofinput.append(i)
if(len(listofinput)>1):
   listofinput = format(tuple(listofinput))
else:
   listofinput='('+listofinput[0]+')'
```